# Create a parameter to find files starting with a specific letter in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm currently studying for my Linux finals and I'm currently struggling with an exercise:

So my script looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" ==  "-e" ]
  then
fullfilename=$(basename $2)
extension=${fullfilename##*.}
filename=${fullfilename%.*}

path="$3"
#string=$( find . -type f -name "*.$extension" )
string=$( find $path -type f -name "*.$extension" ) 

for FILE in $string
do
nam=$( basename $FILE )
DIR=$( dirname $FILE )
#DIR=$( ls -d -1 $PWD/*.$extension )
echo -e "$nam \t $DIR "

done 



 elif [ x$1 = "x-h" ] || [ x$1 = "x--help" ] 
then
echo -e "\nusage: bash filename.sh [parameter] [extension] [directory] \n
     example : bash filename.sh -e txt /home/user/ \n
         Parameters :\n
     \t -e\t \t Default parameter \n
         \t -h or --help\t \t show help \n
     \t -nr \t\t find with no recursion "


elif [ $1 == "-nr" ]
 then
fullfilename=$(basename $2)
extension=${fullfilename##*.}
filename=${fullfilename%.*}

path="$3"
#string=$( find . -type f -name "*.$extension" )
string=$( find $path -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.$extension" )

for FILE in $string
do
nam=$( basename $FILE )
DIR=$( dirname $FILE )
#DIR=$( ls -d -1 $PWD/*.$extension )
echo -e "$nam \t $DIR "

done

else
echo "use -h or --help for help"
fi
```

The goal of this script is to find files with a certain extension and show the directory they're in.

What I have to do now is to add a parameter "-fl" that will only search for files starting with the letter you put behind the parameter (Example ./filename.sh -fl m txt /home/user would only search for txt files starting with the letter "m")

Any idea how to implement this into my script?

I think it would have something to do with this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 = "-fl" ] 
then
echo [$(echo "$2")]*
fi
```

But don't know how to add it without messing up.

Comment: `"$2"*` will expand to every file in the current directory beginning with what's in `$2`

Comment: as you're testing for other command line options to your script already, with that chained if ... then ... elif ... then .... else ... fi  construct,  consider to change to a  case .. esac construct within which you test for matching patterns (those being your command line switches). Also look at the "shift" instruction, which allows you to "consume" command line arguments

Comment: Your quoting for `[ x$1 = "x-h" ] || [ x$1 = "x--help" ] ` is exactly backwards -- you're quoting the things that need no quoting and leaving the things that need to be quoted unquoted. `[ "$1" = -h ] || [ "$1" = --help ]` is correct; the `x`s aren't needed for any shell built since the 1970s.

Comment: ...also, every other place you use parameter expansions as arguments they need to be quoted as well, ie. `name=$(basename "$file")`. Also, `echo -e` isn't well-specified by POSIX and should be replaced by `printf`,

Comment: Finally, if your shell is bash, you can create an array of files starting with the character in `$2` as `files=( "$2"* )`. That array can then be expanded as `"${files[@]}"` (just using `"$files" will expand to only the first file in the array).

Comment: Also, `==` isn't a POSIX-specified construct in `[ ]`. `=` is the POSIX-specified operator for string comparisons. If you _don't_ want to comply with POSIX, use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` -- it's more powerful and less error-prone in general.

Comment: Also, shame, shame, shame for asking people to do your homework for you. Asking about a specific, more focused question ("how do I get a list of files starting with a single letter?", or "how do I parse command-line arguments") is fine... but also, you could probably find those targeted questions here on StackOverflow already answered, and not need to be bothering us at all.

Comment: ...and, well, since there would be individual answers for the smaller questions this big question is composed of, it probably should be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @WannaBeProg Perhaps next time when a question's too broad that people would be so hotheaded to give answers without making heavy remarks, you can just consider asking in a bit more interactive places like forums e.g. [LinuxQuestions.org](http://linuxquestions.org). Your question is already valid despite it being a homework since you already tried a big part yourself as shown in your code.

Comment: I believe it's not necessary for people to show superiority most of the time especially when they're really not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard actually to try fixing your code so I made a version of it just for fun. You may refer to this. For anything you wouldn't understand on it, reading the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) would give much explanation. With it you wouldn't even need wikis or tutorials if you're diligent enough trust me.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_EXT=''
CONFIG_FIRST_LETTER=''
CONFIG_NO_RECURSION=false
CONFIG_PATH=''

function error {
    echo "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

function show_help_info {
    echo "Usage: $0 -e ext [-fl letter] [-nr] [--] directory
Example: $0 -e txt -fl c -- /home/user/
Options:
  -e          Specifies extension.
  -fl         Specifies first letter.
  -nr         Find with no recursion.
  -h, --help  Show help."
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -e)
        [[ -n $2 ]] || error "Option '-e' doesn't have an argument."
        CONFIG_EXT=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -nr)
        CONFIG_NO_RECURSION=true
        ;;
    -fl)
        [[ -n $2 ]] || error "Option '-fl' doesn't have an argument."
        [[ $2 == [[:alpha:]] ]] || error "Argument to option '-fl' must be a single letter."
        CONFIG_FIRST_LETTER=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -h|--help)
        show_help_info
        exit 1
        ;;
    -*)
        error "Invalid option: $1"
        ;;
    --)
        CONFIG_PATH=$2
        ;;
    *)
        CONFIG_PATH=$1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [[ -z $CONFIG_EXT ]]; then
    error "Extension was not specified. Please use -h or --help for usage info."
elif [[ -z $CONFIG_PATH ]]; then
    error "Target path was not specified. Please use -h or --help for usage info."
fi

FL_ARGS=()
[[ -n $CONFIG_FIRST_LETTER ]] && FL_ARGS=('-name' "${CONFIG_FIRST_LETTER}*")

MAXDEPTH_ARGS=()
[[ $CONFIG_NO_RECURSION == true ]] && MAXDEPTH_ARGS=('-maxdepth' 1)

while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "${FILE##*/}" "${FILE%/*}"
done < <(exec find "$CONFIG_PATH" "${MAXDEPTH_ARGS[@]}" -type f "${FL_ARGS[@]}" -name "*.${CONFIG_EXT}")

# Similar:
#
# find "$CONFIG_PATH" "${MAXDEPTH_ARGS[@]}" -type f "${FL_ARGS[@]}" -name "*.${CONFIG_EXT}" -printf '%f\t%H\n'
```

Example:

```
bash temp.sh /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/ -e m4 -fl c
```

Output:

```
configmake.m4   /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
codeset.m4      /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
closeout.m4     /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
closedir.m4     /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
close.m4        /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
close-stream.m4 /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
clock_time.m4   /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
chown.m4        /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
chdir-long.m4   /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
canonicalize.m4 /var/tmp/tar-1.27.1/m4
```

Comment: Hello konsolebox, I appreciate your help on this one.
I wasn't looking for answers for my homework, just some help on how to get started for one exercise (searched 1hr on the internet for it) and you were probably the only one really helping me so I'm grateful for that. Also thanks for the code, even if I'm not going to use it (I wouldn't learn anything from c/p) it will probably be useful for later. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @WannaBeProg I made an important fix. I hope you recheck.